# Mostrar el teclado cuando el menu "SearchView" está expandido

Tags: android, sql, searchview

Tengo un *SearchView* y cuando el usuario gira el dispositivo quiero que se muestre el teclado si estaba escribiendo pero no lo consigo, sólo se muestra en vertical y no en horizontal ¿Alguna idea?

Dentro del método `onCreateOptionsMenu` tengo puesto lo siguiente:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchQuery) && buscando) {
    searchItem.expandActionView();
    searchView.setQuery(searchQuery, false); //Al poner true se cierra la aplicación
    searchView.setFocusable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres mantener el mismo layout y evitar que se destruya y vuelva a recrearse añade esta línea a la activity en el Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    .../>
        ...
</activity>
```

Deberías poder cambiar de orientación y mantener el teclado activo

Documentación:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

> For example, the following manifest code declares an activity that
>   handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability
>   change:
>
> Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the
>   MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged(). This method is
>   passed a Configuration object that specifies the new device
>   configuration. By reading fields in the Configuration, you can
>   determine the new configuration and make appropriate changes by
>   updating the resources used in your interface. At the time this method
>   is called, your activity's Resources object is updated to return
>   resources based on the new configuration, so you can easily reset
>   elements of your UI without the system restarting your activity.
>
> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
>   value. That is, you must decalare
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
>   application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
>   handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
>   does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
>   higher device).